# spark3 executor native memory management

Tags: apache-spark

i have a spark sql job execute on spark3 version. i config my job

```
    set spark.executor.memory=8G;
    set spark.executor.cores=3;
    set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=3072;
```

and i didn't use the off-heap memory.
but encounter error:Container killed by YARN for exceeding physical memory limits. 12.1 GB of 11 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead。
i open the executor rss report config. the memory report below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFqFx.png)

what make me confuse is why rss memory is not sum of on-heap memory、off-memory、direct-pool memory、mapped-pool memory。
is there any else component that not include here and how to fix it?